# animation render playback hidden on OS X

Tags: animation, osx

When I "play rendered animation" the playback is hidden under the gui and I have to minimize the entire gui to view it.  It doesn't matter which display option I choose in the render panel.  Single frame renders display correctly in whatever display option is selected.  Macbook Pro retina with Mavericks 10.9.4.  Can't figure this one out!!

Comment: Works fine for me on archlinux with openbox, but I imagine this is OS (and maybe even DE) specific. Sounds like blender ought to ensure the window is focused or something..

Comment: I can confirm the same behaviour on OS X. But it's probably best to report this as a bug: https://developer.blender.org